# C# orderby over list of objects using an int attribute of object

Tags: c#, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort an array of objects by the weight (int) of each object. The code I am working with is:

```
Node[] sortedNodes = nodeArray.OrderBy(x => x.getWeight());
```

I also tried something like:

```
IEnumerable<Node> sortedNodes = nodeArray.OrderBy
(node => node.getWeight, IComparable<int>);
```

I was wondering if anyone could help send me in the right direction.

**Edit:**
I am getting the following error:

> Error 1   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   26  34  HuffmanCode

Comment: Is getWeight a method or a property?

Comment: @Etienne getWeight is a method.

Comment: NET conventions says it should be a property. But it's just a convention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is almost right - if you want an ordered sequence, you can use:

```
IEnumerable<Node> sortedNodes = nodeArray.OrderBy(node => node.getWeight());
```

The overload which takes an `IComparer<int>` is not required since there is a sensible default way of comparing int values.

Or if you want to create a sorted array:

```
Node[] sortedNodes = nodeArray.OrderBy(x => x.getWeight()).ToArray();
```

Your example won't compile since there is no implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<Node>` to `Node[]` so the call to `ToArray` is required.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate both answers. Code is up and running now. Have a great day!

Comment: I think it should be `OrderBy(x.getWeight)` or `OrderBy(x => x.getWeight())` because `getWeight` is a method

Comment: of course I was wrong about `OrderBy(x.getWeight)`. Method group conversion is not applicable in this case :)